# What is the "if-else" ambiguity in C?

Tags: c, language-theory

In the "C Programming Language" (1988) by Kernighan and Ritchie, on p. 234, concerning the grammar of the C language, it reads

> ...this grammar is acceptable to the YACC parser-generator. It has only one conflict, generated by the if-else ambiguity.

What are they referring to? What is the "if-else ambiguity" and why does it generator a conflict for YACC?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) wikipedia article

Comment: See https://www.epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/if.html: Explains it very well.